# How long to stir-fry vegetables to retain most nutrients?

Tags: vegetables, frying, cooking-time, stir-fry

If I need to stir-fry vegetables, how long is the ideal time? I like stir-frying vegetables (almost my staple food) but I don't want to  lose much of the nutrients.

Comment: What kind of nutrients? You're not going to be able to get very helpful answers if you ask like this. And if you say "the healthy ones", that's definitely off-topic - we're a food and cooking site, not a nutrition site. So if you have some notion of what you care about, you might want to edit your question. Otherwise, it completely depends on the nutrient, so the answers you get are unlikely to mean that much to you.

Comment: I'm going to put this on hold in the meantime to keep people from providing answers that won't help you. If you can clarify, we'll happily reopen it. (But again, if you want to talk about nutrition, that's off topic.)

Comment: @Jefromi Nutrition is 100% about cooking. It is one of the core reasons we eat. The OP is not asking for medical advice?

Comment: @TFD If you ask "how do I preserve nutrients that are good for me?" you are asking a nutritional question. If you ask "how do I preserve vitamin A?" you are asking a cooking question. The OP was not clear, so I put it on hold with the assumption that the question was the former. As I said, if the OP revises this to ask something more specific and answerable, we can reopen it. But nutrition is and always has been off topic; take it to meta if you want to debate it.

Comment: You must have a different post to the one I am reading, where is the "good for me" style bit? Nutrients doesn't mean vitamin A etc. It means anything you eat that the body will digest for growth, carbohydrates are a nutrient

Comment: @TFD Like I said, I had closed it as nutrition-related because, lacking any clarification, the OP was indeed asking an implicit nutrition question: how do I preserve the *important* nutrients. I've reclosed this as "unclear what you're asking" to avoid any further debate, since it should be clear to the OP from the comments that nutrition is off topic.

Comment: @Jefromi where does it say "important nutrients". You are making this up as you go!

Comment: It seems like the wording with "nutrients" alone should qualify it as a nutritional question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Cooking with extreme heat is the killer of nutrients in vegetables. Therefore in traditional stir frying, timing is important. The goal is to coat all the vegetables with oil and searing their outer surface and not allowing the heat to transfer into the core of the vegetables.

I personally do not like to cook with that kind of a heat, it is just too violent. Instead, I let the vegetable to stay in room temperature and cook them with medium heat, in a regular non-stick pan. However, I stop cooking them while they are still firm, lightly golden and vibrant.

Answer (score 2):

Where do you think these nutrients are going, they can't escape the wok?

Stir-frying by convention is quick, so the internal temperature of the food wont get hot enough to break down any delicate nutrients either